# Write code that find maximum cuts of an iron bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization

I'm currently trying to write a Python programm that can find the maxium cuts for a 5m iron bar.
The allowed cuts are : 0.5m, 1m, 1.2m, and 2m.
Given that I have to find all the combinations that match or get close to 5m.
Combinations exemple:

- 10*0.5 = 5m
- 7*0.5 + 1.2 = 4.7m

The second combination is also good because we cant produce a 0.3m cut so we throw it away.
The order inside a combination dosent matter,

> 7x0.5 + 1.2 = 1.2 + 7x0.5

so we have to count it only once.
So ideally my programm take a file in, and write a file with all the combinations like:

```
c1 = 10*0.5 
c2 = 7*0.5 + 1.2 
....
```

Can anyone share advice from where to start please ? Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize here, because you say maximum cuts which would simply mean 0.5 * 10. If it is simply all cuts possible then this isn't a numerical optimization problem and simply a list all possibilities problem.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I used the knapsack algorithm to find the number of possibilities, but I don't know how to print them all, do you have any advice for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for ?

```
x = [2, 1.2, 1, 0.5]
max_val = 5

def find_next(state, idx, check=False):
    if(idx == len(x)):
        return print_it(state, check)
    if(sum(state) + x[idx] > max_val):
        find_next(state, idx + 1, True)
    else:
        find_next(state + [x[idx]], idx)
        find_next(state, idx + 1)

def print_it(state, check):
    if check:
        print("")
        print(sum(state),state)
    return


find_next([],0)
```

It recursively finds the next value until it runs out of values, and it tracks the current state with a simple list which it prints with `print_it` function. I will leave the formatting and file storage up to you, which can easily be implemented in that function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, i was going in the wrong direction with the knapsack algorithm. Thanks a lot !