# Python code to calculate necessary of Iron Bars

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization

I need your help with this calculation.
I need to obtain the following pieces of iron bars for each corresponding length (where keys = length, values = pieces):
necesar = {
12: 12,
8: 12,
4.55: 4,
4.1: 4,
3.85: 4,
2.65: 316,
2.5: 62,
1.85: 316,
1.5: 12,
1.45: 62,
1.3: 72,
1.1: 18,
}

The vendor sells only iron bars of 12 meters long. So, I need to find the optimal way to cut 12 meters long iron bars so that the waste is minimal.

### Desired Output:

#### Total Bars:

198 pieces x 12m

- 12 x full size bars **(completed)**
- 12 x full size bars cut 8m **(completed)** / 4m
- 12 x 4m bars cut 2.5m **(12/62)** / 1.5m **(completed)**
- etc...

#### Waste:

- 3 x 0.9m
- 2 x 0.75

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65122377/write-code-that-find-maximum-cuts-of-an-iron-bar) but there is only one answer and I am not able to adapt the code to my needs.

Any help is very much appreciated!

**NB: I can not put 2 smaller pieces together to make a bigger one, only cuts.**

Comment: The total number presented in the desired output is pure example. It may be (or not) the correct answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about AI-generated code: `Below is the code that I put together with ChatGPT`, which is [not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: Please don't close it down. I did not know it is not allowed. The question not about Ai. I have presented my code. I can delete that part as it is forbidden.

Comment: It's not so much "forbidden" as it's the fact that AI generated code is _not your own code_, and Stackoverflow exists to help you ask questions about code _you wrote_ that doesn't work: we're here to help _you_ understand what _you_ did wrong. Not help ChatGPT correct its output. So first describe how you'd tackle this (and if you don't know, this isn't a programming problem yet, it's a "true" math problem for asking on the [math.se] site, after reading [their rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and searching their site too of course)

Comment: This is an example of "combinatorial optimization", specifically a kind of problem called the "stock cutting problem". A web search for those terms will find many resources.